# what is difference between "tar -xvf" and "tar xvf" on Linux?

Tags: linux, unix

I am extracting a tar file on linux server using below commands

```
tar xvf httpd-2.2.31.tar
tar -xvf httpd-2.2.31.tar
```

both are having same output, what does hyphen(`-`) mean here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming

Comment: `man tar`? Probably tells you the hyphen is optional?

Answer (score 4):

In this usage, there is no difference.

Both are a shorthand for

```
tar -x -v -f httpd-2.2.31.tar
```

Single character switches can be grouped together eg -xvf
and seemingly unique to tar, the first argument will be treated as switches regardless of whether there is a hyphen.

Comment: Essentially that's a result of failure to standardize variant implementations.  For a similar effect, read the manpage for `ps`.

Answer (score 2):

Difference is in -xvf and xvf is when you want to untar tar file you can give target directory location where you want to untar file if the location is not exist in -xvf it create that directory and untar file, and in xvf if directory is not available it untar on same location